# Failing to scrape a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, spyder

I have problems trying to scrape a web with multiple pages with Spyder: the web has 1 to 6 pages and also a next button. Also, each of one the six pages has 30 results. I've tried two solutions without success.

This is the first one:

```
#SOLUTION 1#
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://store.unionlosangeles.com/collections/outerwear?sort_by=creation_date&page_num=1')

#Imports the HTML of the webpage into python      
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'isp_grid_product')

#Creates data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Link':[''], 'Vendor':[''],'Title':[''], 'Price':['']})

#Scrape the data
for i in range (1,7): #I've also tried with range (1,6), but it gives 5 pages instead of 6.
    url = "https://store.unionlosangeles.com/collections/outerwear?sort_by=creation_date&page_num="+str(i)+""
    postings = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'isp_grid_product')
    for post in postings:
        link = post.find('a', class_ = 'isp_product_image_href').get('href')
        link_full = 'https://store.unionlosangeles.com'+link
        vendor = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_vendor').text.strip()
        title = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_title').text.strip()
        price = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_price_wrapper').text.strip()
        df = df.append({'Link':link_full, 'Vendor':vendor,'Title':title, 'Price':price}, ignore_index = True)
```

The output of this code is a data frame with 180 rows (30 x 6), but it repeats the results
of the first page. Thus, my first 30 rows are the first 30 results of the first page, and the rows 31-60 are again the same results of the first page and so on.

Here is the second solution I tried:

```
### SOLUTION 2 ###

from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://store.unionlosangeles.com/collections/outerwear?sort_by=creation_date&page_num=1')

#Imports the HTML of the webpage into python      
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
soup

#Create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Link':[''], 'Vendor':[''],'Title':[''], 'Price':['']})

#Scrape data
i = 0
while i < 6:
    
    postings = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'isp_grid_product')
    len(postings)

    for post in postings:
        link = post.find('a', class_ = 'isp_product_image_href').get('href')
        link_full = 'https://store.unionlosangeles.com'+link
        vendor = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_vendor').text.strip()
        title = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_title').text.strip()
        price = post.find('div', class_ = 'isp_product_price_wrapper').text.strip()
        df = df.append({'Link':link_full, 'Vendor':vendor,'Title':title, 'Price':price}, ignore_index = True)

    #Imports the next pages HTML into python
    next_page = 'https://store.unionlosangeles.com'+soup.find('div', class_ = 'page-item next').get('href')
    page = requests.get(next_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    i += 1
```

The problem with this second solution is that the program cannot recognize the attribute "get" in `next_page`, for reasons I cannot grasp (I haven't had this problem in other webs with paginations). Thus, I get only the first page and not the others.

How can I fix the code to properly scrape all 180 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via javascript. You can simulate these calls with `requests` module. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = "https://store.unionlosangeles.com/collections/outerwear?sort_by=creation_date&page_num=1"
api_url = "https://cdn-gae-ssl-premium.akamaized.net/categories_navigation"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

params = {
    "page_num": 1,
    "store_id": "",
    "UUID": "",
    "sort_by": "creation_date",
    "facets_required": "0",
    "callback": "",
    "related_search": "1",
    "category_url": "/collections/outerwear",
}

q = parse_qs(
    urlparse(soup.select_one("#isp_search_result_page ~ script")["src"]).query
)

params["store_id"] = q["store_id"][0]
params["UUID"] = q["UUID"][0]

all_data = []
for params["page_num"] in range(1, 7):
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    for i in data["items"]:
        link = i["u"]
        vendor = i["v"]
        title = i["l"]
        price = i["p"]

        all_data.append([link, vendor, title, price])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["link", "vendor", "title", "price"])
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
print("Total items =", len(df))
```

Prints:

| link | vendor | title | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /products/barn-jacket | Essentials | BARN JACKET | 250 |
| /products/work-vest-2 | Essentials | WORK VEST | 120 |
| /products/tailored-track-jacket | Martine Rose | TAILORED TRACK JACKET | 1206 |
| /products/work-vest-1 | Essentials | WORK VEST | 120 |
| /products/60-40-cloth-bug-anorak-1tone | Kapital | 60/40 Cloth BUG Anorak (1Tone) | 747 |
| /products/smooth-jersey-stand-man-woman-track-jkt | Kapital | Smooth Jersey STAND MAN & WOMAN Track JKT | 423 |
| /products/supersized-sports-jacket | Martine Rose | SUPERSIZED SPORTS JACKET | 1695 |
| /products/pullover-vest | Nicholas Daley | PULLOVER VEST | 267 |
| /products/flannel-polkadot-x-bandana-reversible-1st-jkt-1 | Kapital | FLANNEL POLKADOT X BANDANA REVERSIBLE 1ST JKT | 645 |
| /products/60-40-cloth-bug-anorak-1tone-1 | Kapital | 60/40 Cloth BUG Anorak (1Tone) | 747 |

```
Total items = 175
```

Comment: Thank you, @Andrej Kesely. Your answer helps me a lot. Just an additional question. Why the program gives 175 elements instead of 180?

Comment: @IvanA.RamírezZapata Because on the last page there are only 25 items.